# Uninitialized Constant ConfirmationsController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, routes

I'm trying to do a custom override of devise confirmations so that a new user creates a password after they receive a confirmation email.  This is in the devise wiki and can be found [here.](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Override-confirmations-so-users-can-pick-their-own-passwords-as-part-of-confirmation-activation)

When I navigate to the confirmation link, I am, however confronted by the following error

> uninitialized constant ConfirmationsController

I've seen this before when I flubbed the name of a controller class (left out an s or something similar), however I can't find anything like that here.  The two relevant files I can think to present are my controller and my routes, relevant to devise.

**Here's my controller:**

```
class Users::ConfirmationsController < Devise::ConfirmationsController
  # Remove the first skip_before_filter (:require_no_authentication) if you
  # don't want to enable logged users to access the confirmation page.
  skip_before_filter :require_no_authentication
  skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!

  # GET /resource/confirmation/new
  def new
    super
  end

  # POST /resource/confirmation
  # def create
  #   super
  # end

  # GET /resource/confirmation?confirmation_token=abcdef

  # PUT /resource/confirmation
  def update
    with_unconfirmed_confirmable do
      if @confirmable.has_no_password?
        @confirmable.attempt_set_password(params[:user])
        if @confirmable.valid? and @confirmable.password_match?
          do_confirm
        else
          do_show
          @confirmable.errors.clear #so that we wont render :new
        end
      else
        @confirmable.errors.add(:email, :password_already_set)
      end
    end

    if !@confirmable.errors.empty?
      self.resource = @confirmable
      render 'devise/confirmations/new' #Change this if you don't have the views on default path
    end
  end

  # GET /resource/confirmation?confirmation_token=abcdef
  def show
    with_unconfirmed_confirmable do
      if @confirmable.has_no_password?
        do_show
      else
        do_confirm
      end
    end
    unless @confirmable.errors.empty?
      self.resource = @confirmable
      render 'devise/confirmations/new' #Change this if you don't have the views on default path
    end
  end

  protected

  # The path used after resending confirmation instructions.
  def after_resending_confirmation_instructions_path_for(resource_name)
    super(resource_name)
  end

  # The path used after confirmation.
  def after_confirmation_path_for(resource_name, resource)
    super(resource_name, resource)
  end


  def with_unconfirmed_confirmable
    @confirmable = User.find_or_initialize_with_error_by(:confirmation_token, params[:confirmation_token])
    if !@confirmable.new_record?
      @confirmable.only_if_unconfirmed {yield}
    end
  end

  def do_show
    @confirmation_token = params[:confirmation_token]
    @requires_password = true
    self.resource = @confirmable
    render 'devise/confirmations/show' #Change this if you don't have the views on default path
  end

  def do_confirm
    @confirmable.confirm!
    set_flash_message :notice, :confirmed
    sign_in_and_redirect(resource_name, @confirmable)
  end
  end
end
```

And here's the routes relevant to devise:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: {
    sessions: 'users/sessions',
confirmations: "confirmations"
}

as :user do
  patch '/user/confirmation' => 'confirmations#update', :via => :patch, :as => :update_user_confirmation
end
```

Please feel free to ask for any other code that you think might be helpful.  Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shouldn't you be going to 'users/confirmations#update'? not 'confirmations#update' based on your class name of Users::ConfirmationsController

I normally wrap the routes in namespaces, but for simplicity, you should probably update your patch.